# how to use java quartz weekly calendar for finding last working day

Tags: java, calendar

Can anyone tell me how to use quartz weekly calendar.

I am trying to find the last working day from the current day for which i am trying to exclude

weekends and holidays.

But in Quartz weekly calendar i am not able to find methods  for the normal date manipulations

which i can do with java.util.calendar.

can anyone tell me how to integrate these both calendar's functions?

Answer (score 0):

I would have the task execute every day and check to see if its the last working day of the week. Holidays are very region even business/industry specific. (when banks are closed other business may be open) I don't believe you will find a standard library which does this.